# Is the ServerAction Method Required in a ImapServerCommandAction?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, arcgis-web-adf

I am using an ESRI toolbar control buddied with a map control.

I am using a command.  Below is a simple example.

My question is to clarify - having the ServerAction method is a requirement when you are using the toolbar control and server side action?

```
public class CustomExtent : IMapServerCommandAction //implements the IServerAction interface
{
    public CustomExtent()
    {
    }
```

```
#region IServerAction Members

public void ServerAction(ToolbarItemInfo info)
{
   Map map = info.BuddyControls[0] as Map;
   map.Extent = new Envelope(-90, 10, -70, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As quoted from the web ADF reference [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ServerAction_Method/000m00000r3v000000/):

> Classes that will be used as the
>   ServerActionClass for a toolbar item
>   must implement this method.

So, unless I misunderstood the question, the answer is yes.

Comment: GuillaumeC:  I read that piece in the documentation which is why I was wanting a clarification to be sure I did not miss anything.  

I was also curious if someone has been able to implement it differently.  

I am thinking about creating a toolbar class that just handles the ServerAction Methods that just call and pass parameters to my other classes.